# Offline BaseMap using ArcGIS in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

How to add `arcgis sdk` file in `android studio` while i create offline map using `arcgis`. i follow the tutorial [blog.esri.com](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/05/20/using-the-arcgis-android-sdk-with-android-studio-part-1/) but still confuse where i add `jniLib` folder as read in tutorials "`Create a HelloWorld/HelloWorld/src/main/jniLibs folder in your project.`"

i also can't find the any video tutorial to find the best solution. please help me to how to add these folders 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial is quite outdated.
You should specify arcgis-android in your gradle and that's it.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.7'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/install-and-set-up.htm